# Unable to replace item with chinese word in partition key header in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, go, sdk, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to use golang to do CURD operation in Azure Cosmos db using github.com/vippsas/go-cosmosdb package.

Everything works fine except trying to Create、Replace documents with chinese character in the x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey.

Document sample data, partition key is /method

```
{
 "id": "9289b3f5-5830-4589-ab7d-6c0efbb4150e",
 "method": "日",
 "endpoint": "/api/savecsv?operator=jimmylin",
 "operator": "jimmy",
 "execTime": 1622867229,
 "payload": "abc.json"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
    client := cosmosapi.New()
    _, _, err = client.CreateDocument(ctx, "dbid", "contid", &log, cosmosapi.CreateDocumentOptions{PartitionKeyValue: log.Method})
    if err != nil {
        err = tracerr.New(err.Error())
        tracerr.PrintSourceColor(err, 2)
    }
```

I also printed out the partition key that is handled in /vippsas/go-cosmosdb package. the output is:

```
x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey:["日"]
```

Here is error I have:

```
The JSON, SQL, or JavaScript in the request body is invalid
```

If I change /method to English, It works just fine.

If I use JS SDKs works fine as well(chinese character partition key).

I believe either JS SDKs or the package I use are all based on Azure Cosmos DB Restful APIs.
I think this package is likely to be missing something.

Comment: What’s the error you’re getting? Please edit your question and provide that. Also include a sample value.

Comment: @GauravMantri I've updated it, if there is anything needs to be included, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Cosmos db is only supporting Unicode or ASCII in x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey while github.com/vippsas/go-cosmosdb package is using json.Marshal which internally transforms Unicode to Chinese characters automatically.

The only way to solve it is using English as partition key when creating documents.